# Simultaneous mount of multiple components overrides redux state

Tags: redux, react-redux

In my react-redux application, when I mount 2 components together, state of first is being over-ridden by second.

In my first component, I have following state and actions defined:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    comp1: state.comp1,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: {
      action1: bindActionCreators(action1, dispatch),
      action2: bindActionCreators(action2, dispatch),
    }
  };
}
```

And the second component looks something like this:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    comp2: state.comp2,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: {
      action3: bindActionCreators(action3, dispatch),
      action4: bindActionCreators(action4, dispatch),
    }
  };
}
```

But when both the components are finally mounted, only second components state and actions remain. And 1st component's state and action become undefined.

I simply render the components this way:

```
<Comp1/>
<Comp2/>
```

Redux version: 3.7.2
React-redux version: 5.0.6

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi. Can you show us the snippet of code where you mount the two components?

Comment: @Andrea I just edited my question to specify that